# Change chrome autofill yellow with this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm sick trying to make this working for me on my website but it is impossible.. I think I'm doing something wrong..

I have this jquery code from BenjaminMiles posted from his website:

```js
<script>
 if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") >= 0) {
  $(window).load(function(){
   $('input:-webkit-autofill').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).after(this.outerHTML).remove();
    $('input[name=' + name + ']').val(text);
   });
  });
 }
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="text" />
```

but still doesn't work... also tried the box-shadow trick, but doesn't work for me because I'm using an input with a background image.

I have the code above inside the body tag, so.. what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might not need jQuery. Use `transition` to make the yellow background go away. All you have to do is as follows:

```
 input:-webkit-autofill,
 input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
 input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
 input:-webkit-autofill:active {
        transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
```

To change text color, add

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;
```

replace `white` with the color of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

[vyastech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5059689/vyastech) fix is nice, but you should play with the "delay" of the transition in place of "duration"

```
input:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill {
  transition: background-color 0s 3600s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like below code work

```
    // Change the white to any color ;)
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
```

you can try using below code to change text color:

```
   -webkit-text-fill-color: yellow !important;
```

using jquery below code will work

```
    if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('input[name="password"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
}
```

Comment: turn off autocomplete is not the best idea at all